# Tengo una duda, al momento de leer un archivo de texto en c++ (ifstream)

Tags: c++

Cuando voy visualizar los datos que capture en un archivo txt en c++, al iniciar el bucle no me abría correctamente y me guiaron diciéndome que: Tenia que leer primero la primer variable que haya capturado y después iniciar el bucle, y seguido leer las demás variables y una vez terminado de imprimir en pantalla todo, cerrar leyendo la primera variable.

Mi duda es por qué se hace esto?

Aquí una parte de mi código donde esta la que comente:

```
        ver>>nombre;
        while(!ver.eof()){
            ver>>codigo;
            ver>>precioxunidad;
            ver>>unidadtotal;
            ver>>preciototal;

            cout<<"\n>>Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
            cout<<">>Codigo: "<<codigo<<endl;
            cout<<">>Precio Por Unidad: "<<precioxunidad<<endl;
            cout<<">>Unidades Totales: "<<unidadtotal<<endl;
            cout<<">>Precio Total: "<<preciototal<<endl;
            cout<<"........................"<<endl<<endl;;

            ver>>nombre;
    }
        ver.close();}
```

*Aqui la funcion en la que hice la lectura:*

````
void verarticulos (ifstream &ver)
{

    system("cls");
    string nombre;
    string codigo;
    string precioxunidad;
    string unidadtotal;
    string preciototal;

    ver.open("Inventario.txt", ios::in);
    cout<<"\t\t\t********************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t*   REGISTROS DEL INVENTARIO   *"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t********************************"<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    if(ver.is_open()){
        ver>>nombre;
        while(!ver.eof()){
            ver>>codigo;
            ver>>precioxunidad;
            ver>>unidadtotal;
            ver>>preciototal;

            cout<<"\n>>Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
            cout<<">>Codigo: "<<codigo<<endl;
            cout<<">>Precio Por Unidad: "<<precioxunidad<<endl;
            cout<<">>Unidades Totales: "<<unidadtotal<<endl;
            cout<<">>Precio Total: "<<preciototal<<endl;
            cout<<"........................"<<endl<<endl;;

            ver>>nombre;
    }
        ver.close();}
    else{
        cout<<"Error."<<endl;
        cout<<"El archivo no se puedo abrir."<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
    ```
````

Comment: Coloca un título descriptivo y relativo al problema presentado por favor

Comment: Si, Muchas Gracias ya lo cambie, espero que se entienda.

Answer (score 0):

La lectura de `nombre` se hace porque `eof()` sólo será verdadero si ha habido una lectura y se ha llegado al final del fichero. Si después de leer no es el final, se comienza el bucle.

La lectura de `nombre` al final es para leer el siguiente bloque. Igual, si se ha llegado al final del archivo el bucle termina.